# The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, exception, dart

I am creating an App and I am new in flutter, dart. I have problem in "context". I want to replace the page/screen onTab(). But I'm having the following error:

```
> ══════ Exception caught by gesture ════════════════════════ The
> following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture: The
> method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null. Receiver: null
> Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()
```

Here is my code:

```
class Theorytest extends StatelessWidget {

    Widget  customcard(String testName ){
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){

                      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(

              builder: (context) => GetTestData(),
           ),
           );
          },
          child: Material(     
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
            elevation: 20.0,
            child : Container(
              child: Column(
                children : <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 20.0, 10.0, 20.0),
                    child: Text( testName,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                    ),
                    ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: ListView(
          children : <Widget>[
            customcard('Theory Test 1'),
            customcard('Theory Test 2'),
            customcard('Theory Test 3'),
            customcard('Theory Test 4'),
            customcard('Theory Test 5'),
            customcard('Theory Test 6'),
            customcard('Theory Test 7'),
            customcard('Theory Test 8'),
            customcard('Theory Test 9'),
            customcard('Theory Test 10'),
            customcard('Theory Test 11'),
            customcard('Theory Test 12'),
            customcard('Theory Test 13'),
            customcard('Theory Test 14'),
            customcard('Theory Test 15')          
          ]
        ),
      );
    }
```

This is the code error. I don't know why context is not working for me.

[image]

Comment: Possibly dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56362432/nosuchmethoderror-the-method-ancestorstateoftype-was-called-on-null-with-awai

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem (why context is not working for you) is because there is no object of **BuildContext** in your **customCard** method

There are several ways to achieve this..

One way is to add a **BuildContext** parameter in your method Like this

```
  Widget customcard(BuildContext context, String testName) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => GetTestData(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
          elevation: 20.0,
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 20.0, 10.0, 20.0),
                  child: Text(
                    testName,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then your ListView children will be like

```
customCard(context, "Theory Test 1")
```

Another way to do it is to create a stateless widget and return the customcard in the build method

```
class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  String testName;
  CustomCard(this.testName);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => GetTestData(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
          elevation: 20.0,
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 20.0, 10.0, 20.0),
                  child: Text(
                    testName,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then your ListView children will be like...

```
CustomCard("Theory Test 1")
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you  very much. This solved my problem. Again thanks Josteve Adekanbi