# Navigate from initState returns 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-navigation, flutter-state

I'm listening to database changes (firestore) in the initState. On a specific change I need to route the user to another screen.

My initState function:

```
      @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('groups')
        .where('members', arrayContains: globals.user.userId)
        .limit(1)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      event.docs.forEach((doc) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            '/GroupScreen', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      });
    });
  }
```

There are **two situations**:

1. The first one is when the database change takes effect **before** the user opened the app. Then when the user opens the app, he routes directly to the other screen **without any problem**.
2. On the other hand, when the app is open, and the database change take effect, the user is redirect to the other screen with the above error:

> Exception caught by scheduler library The method
> 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried
> calling: findAncestorStateOfType()

I don't understand why the error takes effect only on the second situation.

Please help me to figure out what am I doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

## Extra information (full code):

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreen createState() => _MainScreen();
}

class _MainScreen extends State<MainScreen> {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  List<String> favoritGroupsList = List<String>();
  bool isLoading = true;
  Stream _groupsStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    checkFirstScreen();
    _groupsStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('groups')
        .where('guests', arrayContains: globals.user.userId)
        .orderBy('status')
        .snapshots();
    if (_groupsStream != null) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('groups')
          .where('members', arrayContains: globals.user.userId)
          .limit(1)
          .snapshots()
          .listen((event) {
        event.docs.forEach((doc) {
          joinUserToGroup(context, doc.id);
        });
      });
    }
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => {
          initFunctions(),
          Network().getAvailableFriends().then((value) => showSnackBar())
        });
  }

  void initFunctions() async {
    await Network().getAllUser();
    await Network().getUser();
    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
        .
        .
        .
      ),
    );
  }

joinUserToGroup(BuildContext context, String groupId) {
    globals.tempGroup.groupId = groupId;
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        '/GroupScreen', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    _groupsStream = null;
  }
}
```

The problem is in the Navigator in joinUserToGroup function.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should wait until the data will be available and for that put the code inside a function that have Future like this

```
Future<viod> someFunction() async{
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('groups')
        .where('guests', arrayContains: globals.user.userId)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      event.docs.forEach((doc) {
        if (doc['members'].contains(globals.user.userId)) {
          SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                '/GroupScreen', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
          });
        }
      });
    });
}
```

then add the function to the initState()

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
  someFunction();
  }
```

i think it's maybe work

Comment: Hey @ahmed thanks for replying. I have edited my question to make it more clear. 

If the database change take effect and only then the user logs into the app. everything is ok, the user is redirected to the other page without a problem. 

On the other hand, when the change takes effect when the user is already logged in (the app is open), the user is redirected as expected but with the above error.

I have tried your answer and it didn't helped me.

Comment: this [link from flutter doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findAncestorStateOfType.html) explain what you doin wrong and it has something do with context

Comment: The document does not help much :/

Comment: you problem is with navigation and context so try to find another way to navigate the page, if you add a little more code it maybe help to be understanded

Comment: What other information would you like me to provide?

Comment: like what kind of class you are in and what you are extending where you want to send the data,and as i told you your problem is with context and navigator so if you want to solve your code or know more go search for it in flutter navigator

Comment: this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook#navigation) is all kind of navigation in flutter

Comment: this [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushAndRemoveUntil.html) is explain how to use your rout, i really couldn't understand why you use this at the beginning of the app

Comment: i think i found your problem is with context and you calling navigator outside the context which is why you get this error so you have to provide the context here is the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711890/the-method-findancestorstateoftype-was-called-on-null-in-flutter-dart)

Answer (score 0):

i found your problem is with `BuildContext` context and you calling navigator outside the `BuildContext` which is why you get this error so you have to provide the context because without a context you can't make a new screen maybe this link help you [The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null in flutter dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711890/the-method-findancestorstateoftype-was-called-on-null-in-flutter-dart)

```
 void someFunction(BuildContext context) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('groups')
        .where('guests', arrayContains: globals.user.userId)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      event.docs.forEach((doc) {
        if (doc['members'].contains(globals.user.userId)) {
          SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                '/GroupScreen', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
          });
        }
      });
    });
}
void initState() {
    super.initState();
  someFunction();
  }
```

Comment: I will check this out, but it still does not help me to understand why everything is working ok on situation 1 but not in situation 2.

Comment: Also the situation is very different, while I'm trying to navigate to another page from the initState this guy is trying to do that from a widget.

Comment: will you still use the context so you both have the same situation

Comment: read this [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushAndRemoveUntil.html) so you can understand what you doing wrong in navigatore, as i told you if you add more information i could help you more

Comment: Hey @ahmed. First of all thanks a lot for all the help. Appreciate.
I have added much more information in the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

do you get any error like red line under the code because your code should not work until
you provide the right parameter like this code

```
joinUserToGroup(BuildContext context, String groupId) {
    globals.tempGroup.groupId = groupId;

   return Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    '/GroupScreen',
                    (route) => false);
              },
    _groupsStream = null;
  }
}
```

i think that's all you need  to make your app work if you get a new error please add in a comment

Answer (score 0):

i made your app by providing Navigator outside and i got the same error it's happen because you asking for a new context while the app made the first context in `MaterialApp` and it's illegal in flutter so you have to separate the navigator by put it inside the `Widget` that got the context from First context then use `State Management` to update the Screen i think that is the only way to use this and flutter have weakness for this kind of situation if you try to make you way work is much harder so you better use `State Management Package` like [Provider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) it's easy to understand and for a complicated app like yours it's hard to be made without a state management so in another way your code will never be able to work so try to add more class and separate them and use state management to send the data and check the logic if you do study and read them all you will finish them in two or four days and i got the same problem at first but state management solve this